How to deserialize StakePool account data on a solana native program on chain?
 let stake = try_from_slice_unchecked::<StakePool>(&stake_pool.data.borrow())?;

i have tried try_from, try_from_slice,unchecheked and with schema as well, but I get this same error,
the trait bound `spl_stake_pool::state::StakePool: BorshDeserialize` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `BorshDeserialize`:

Can anyone help me on this?

This is saying you don't have the BorshDeserialize trait in scope/are using the wrong try_from_slice_unchecked. Unfortunately solana_program exports a bunch of borsh versions that all work with a different combination of types. Anyway:
If you're using spl_stake_pool 1.0.0 the correct import is:
use spl_stake_pool::{solana_program::borsh0_10::try_from_slice_unchecked, state::StakePool};

...
let stake = try_from_slice_unchecked::<StakePool>(&bytes).unwrap();

If you're using spl_stake_pool 2.0.0 the correct import is (notice the difference in the borsh import!):
use spl_stake_pool::{solana_program::borsh1::try_from_slice_unchecked, state::StakePool};

...
let stake = try_from_slice_unchecked::<StakePool>(&bytes).unwrap();


Thanks It worked. Can you tell me which account i'm passing wrong in this stakepool instruction https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/15190/account-serialization-error-in-spl-stake-pools-add-validator-instruction
