Account Serialization error in `spl-stake-pool`'s add-validator instruction
I'm trying to Add validator to my stake-pool through a program, When i try to do that i get this error
i use version 2.0.0 of stake-pool and version 2.0.0 of solana
I use this instruction in my program
 &add_validator_to_pool_with_vote(
                stake_pool_program.key,
                &stake,
                stake_pool.key,
                vote_account.key,
                None,
            ),
            &[
                stake_pool.clone(),
                staker.clone(),
                reserve_stake.to_owned(),
                withdraw_authority.to_owned(),
                validator_list.clone(),
                stake_account.to_owned(),
                vote_account.clone(),
                rent.clone(),
                clock.clone(),
                stake_history.clone(),
                stake_config.clone(),
                system_program.clone(),
                stake_program.clone(),
            ],
            &[&[Staker::SEED, &config_pda.key.to_bytes(), &[bump]]],
        )?;

but i get this error . And i get this error, All the account passed up are correct ones. I even checked their lengths and they are also what they should be.
 'Program SPoo1Ku8WFXoNDMHPsrGSTSG1Y47rzgn41SLUNakuHy invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Error: BorshIoError',
    'Program SPoo1Ku8WFXoNDMHPsrGSTSG1Y47rzgn41SLUNakuHy consumed 3284 of 175010 compute units',
    'Program SPoo1Ku8WFXoNDMHPsrGSTSG1Y47rzgn41SLUNakuHy failed: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown',
    'Program CLgQRT48ZE3nqYqS6BGFFLpZYrcyQuFkF7z9gvjcTfgQ consumed 28274 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program CLgQRT48ZE3nqYqS6BGFFLpZYrcyQuFkF7z9gvjcTfgQ failed: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown'

I double checked my accounts, all accounts are right ones, Where is this error coming from?

Please add a minimum reproducible example to directly reproduce the error you're getting in your question.

@Ahri Just updated it, Can you please check

Everything is correct from what I can tell. The error might be in the instruction though -- what version of the program are you using? Typically you should see a line like Instruction: AddValidatorToPool, which isn't even there, so the program is failing to deserialize the instruction, and not the account. Note that the devnet program is out of date, so that might be the source of the problem. You can try testnet or a localnet if needed

Yes, Devnet was the @JonC

Hey @JonC Am having trouble calulating the apy, The APY is too high for some reason, Can you help with that?

Devnet Program for spl-stake-pool is out of date that's why the issue.It works fine on mainnet
